# how to avoid css jitters while applying css border with hover pseudo class

Tags: html, css

when ever i add border to a div using :hover pseudo class it creates jitters.  How to avoid that

```
<div class="mybox">
</div>


//in css file

.mybox:hover{
   border:1px solid gray;
}
```

[This is plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/R4f3xyKTwxxDov5LkOMS?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outline` instead of `border` http://plnkr.co/edit/fijZ4wNazGLlx24gPGqS?p=preview

```
.mybox:hover{
outline: #00FF00 solid thick;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could initially set a white / transparent border and then on hover change the border color to gray.

```css
.mybox {
  border: 1px solid white
}
.mybox:hover {
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a transparent color to start with? Then this would work with any background color?

```css
.mybox {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.mybox:hover {
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
```